# How to write $\cot6\alpha - \cot4\alpha-\cot2\alpha$ in a product (multiplication) form?

Tags: trigonometry

How can I write $$\cot6\alpha - \cot4\alpha-\cot2\alpha$$ in a product (multiplication) form?

I have tried [using wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ctg6%5Calpha%20-%20ctg4%5Calpha%20-%20ctg2%5Calpha) but maybe there is a better and simple form.

Answer (score 1):

*May be* found by simplification;  Let

$$ 2 \alpha= \theta,\; \tan 2 \alpha = \tan \theta = t\; $$

Using tan formula of multiple double/triple angles

$$= \dfrac{1-3t^2}{3t-t^3}-\dfrac{1-t^2}{2t} -\dfrac{1}{t}$$

$$= \dfrac1t[ \dfrac{1-3t^2}{3t-t^3}-\dfrac{t^2-3}{2}] $$

on simplification

$$= -\dfrac{1}{t} (t^4+7) $$

Again use double angle formula to get to $\alpha $ and simplify